# Text Conversion to Embedding and Upserting to the pinecone Vector DB

Tags: python, huggingface, pinecone, openaiembeddings

I am learning Gen AI and I came across following script, it was working for the trainer however it is not working for me, may be due to recent version changes. I am trying to convert text to Vector Embedding and then upload the embedded values to the Pinecone Vector DB. Can someone help me where am I making a mistake?

*I am using Jupyter Notebook to execute above commands*

Error -

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[44], line 8
5 index_name="medical-bot"
7 #Creating Embeddings for Each of The Text Chunks & storing
----> 8 docsearch=pc.from_texts([t.page_content for t in text_chunks], embeddings, index_name=index_name)

AttributeError: 'Pinecone' object has no attribute 'from_texts'

```
def load_data(data):
loader = DirectoryLoader(data, glob="\*.pdf", loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
documents = loader.load()
return documents

extracted_data = load_data("E:\\data")

def text_split(extracted_data):
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=500, chunk_overlap = 20)
text_chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(extracted_data)
return text_chunks

text_chunks = text_split(extracted_data)


def download_hugging_face_embeddings():
embeddings = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
return embeddings

embeddings = download_hugging_face_embeddings()

query_result = embeddings.embed_query("Hello World")
print("Length", len(query_result))

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()
pinecone_api_key = os.getenv("PINECONE_API_KEY")
pinecone_environment = os.getenv("PINECONE_API_ENV")

pc = Pinecone(api_key=pinecone_api_key,
environment=pinecone_environment)
index_name="medical-bot" #My Index Name created in Pinecone DB

#Creating Embeddings for Each of The Text Chunks & storing
docsearch=Pinecone.from_texts([t.page_content for t in text_chunks], embeddings, index_name=index_name)
```